# Simulating before-minibuffer-hook

Tags: hooks, minibuffer

I need a function to execute before the minibuffer is entered, not after (`minibuffer-setup-hook` style). Is there any way I can achieve this effect with advice or other emacs systems?

I would like to defer some minibuffer setup until the minibuffer is actually used, to speed up startup time.

Comment: What do you mean by "*initializes*"? What does it need to execute *after* (not just before)? **Describe your real need:** the *problem* you are trying to solve. Provide more detail. Beware of a possible [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821) here.

Comment: Like Drew says, it will help a great deal if you explain exactly what you want to accomplish. But without knowing that, maybe `defadvice` using `:before` would help? I must admit I'm just guesing though, given the aforementioned lack of information.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, I've clarified my position. The reason I don't say why is any mention of startup time causes causes everyone to go bananas and suggest avoiding the problem with the emacs server or other similar strategies. (ignoring solutions to the original problem) _Those are not options for me_.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "before the minibuffer is entered".  In my world-view, `minibuffer-setup-hook` is run before the minibuffer is entered, so obviously, you mean something different.

Comment: @Stefan one example, `(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'ido-ubiquitous-mode)` doesn't enable `ido-ubiquitous-mode` early enough. You can only tell the mode is enabled on the _second_ time the minibuffer is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that sets up the minibuffer is `read_minibuf` in `minibuf.c`. As of Emacs 24, it is called from the primitives `read-from-minibuffer` and `read-no-blanks-input`, and `Fread_from_minibuffer` is in turned called from `read-string`. The hook `minibuffer-setup-hook` is the first piece of Lisp code that `read_minibuf` executes. If that's too late for you, you're going to need to run your code before any of  `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-no-blanks-input` and `read-string` is executed. In earlier Emacs versions, there were more functions that called `read_minibuf` via C, especially `completing-read`, but these now go via Lisp.

Here's some code for Emacs ≥24.4 that sets up a one-time advice executed before the first time one of these functions executed.

```el
(defun before-first-read-from-minibuffer (&rest ignored)
  (message "Before first read-from-minibuffer")
  (advice-remove 'read-from-minibuffer 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
  (advice-remove 'read-no-blanks-input 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
  (advice-remove 'read-string 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer))
(advice-add 'read-from-minibuffer :before 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
(advice-add 'read-no-blanks-input :before 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
(advice-add 'read-string :before 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
```

The corresponding code with the older advice facility that works in previous Emacs versions would be something like:

```el
(defadvice read-from-minibuffer
    (before before-first-read-from-minibuffer activate)
  (message "Before first read-from-minibuffer")
  (ad-remove-advice 'read-from-minibuffer 'before 'before-first-read-from-minibuffer)
  (ad-activate 'read-from-minibuffer))
```

Comment: Possibly you need to `ad-activate` the advice again? I admit, this is one of the reasons `nadvice` was written. I'll check into this. I admit, it's been a while since I looked at this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid this _still_ isn't early enough. (i.e. for activating modes that redefine `completing-read` like `ido-ubiquitous`). Maybe I can think of another solution...

Comment: So you're [changing the question now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions): you want something that runs before invoking `completing-read`, not something that runs before entering a minibuffer. You can apply the same technique to `completing-read`. But you do seem to be on a spiral where the only thing that's early enough is the first `pre-command-hook`, and if it gets to that, you should just do it in your init file.

Comment: No. I do not expect you to do any more work. You have correctly answered the question, and that is that. I'm just realizing myself that _my_ solution untenable anyway, (although it may be fixable), but I say this only so you know I tested your solution.